# How to trigger MutableLiveData change in ui?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

In my view model I'm using an observable with zip operator to combine two data sets where I then create a new object with data from each source. I post the value of the object to my ui. I need to be able to refresh the content of the object periodically and notify the ui. I have not been able to 1.remove the old data before adding new data to live data object 2.trigger this update in the ui.

**ViewModel**

```
public Observable<?> syncDataSources() {
        return Observable.zip(
                        repository.getFirstData(),
                        repository.getSecondData(URL.SCHEDULE_URL),
                        Pair::new).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap((pair) -> Observable.zip(
                                Observable.just(pair.first),
                                Observable.just(pair.second),
                                (t1, t2) -> {
                                    getSyncedData(t1, t2);
                                    return Observable.empty();
                                }
                        ).retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
                            if (error instanceof IOException) {
                                return Observable.just(null);
                            }
                            return Observable.error(error);
                        }))
                        .doOnError(Throwable::getMessage));
    }

    public void getSyncedData(FirstData firstData, SecondData secondData) {
        //code to create new object from both data sets 
        combinedList.add(dataAdded);
        syncedDataLiveList.postValue(combinedList);
        refreshSyncedData();
    }

    public void refreshSyncedData(){
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                //code to add data to syncedDataLiveList
//new data is added to syncedDataLiveList, but doesn't trigger data change in ui 
                    combinedList.add(dataAdded);
                    syncedDataLiveList.postValue(combinedList);
                }
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<SyncedData>> getSyncedDataLiveList() {
        return syncedDataLiveList;
    }
```

**Fragment**

```
    viewModel.syncDataSources().subscribe();

    videoViewModel.getSyncedDataLiveList().observeForever(new Observer<List<SyncedData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<SyncedData> syncedData) {
                //syncedData is returned only on the initial build
            }
        });
```

How can I clear the old data from the MutableLiveData list before adding the new data and trigger this change in the ui?

Answer (score 0):

@KoolKeith, in the fragment what is `getWatchNowLiveList()`, it has to be:

```
videoViewModel.getSyncedDataLiveList().observeForever(new Observer<List<SyncedData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<SyncedData> syncedData) {
            //syncedData is returned only on the initial build
        }
    });
```

You need to observe `MutableLiveData` in the Activity or Fragment.

Comment: I accidentally copied the wrong part of my code, I've fixed it above. I am observing getSyncedDataLiveList() in my fragment, but thank you for pointing out my error.